# Hide background graphics on inserting a new slide to a presentation programmatically

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, powerpoint, office-interop

here is my problem, I am inserting a slide to a presentation with different background, but I don’t know how to „Hide background graphics“ on the background of thenew slide. So far my code looks like:

```
        //Create a background color
        Color myForegroundColor = Color.Aqua;
        int oleColor = ColorTranslator.ToOle(myForegroundColor);

        //Set the background color of teh slide
        lPresentation.Slides[2].FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        lPresentation.Slides[2].Background.Fill.Background();
        lPresentation.Slides[2].Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = oleColor;
        lPresentation.Slides[2].Background.Fill.Solid();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also want to set .DisplayMasterShapes to false

And as a matter of curiosity, when using .NET, is it really necessary to repeat all the lPresentation.Slides[2] stuff for each line?

Or can you do something like:

```
With lPresentation.Slides[2]
  .Property = Value
  .OtherProperty = OtherValue
  .Etc = "And so forth"
End With
```

In VBA/VB, doing so would be considered best practice ... less typing, so fewer chances for errors, more readable and actually a bit faster to execute.  Considering that I never seem to see it done this way in .NET, I'm guessing that it's not part of the package.

Comment: When using C# it is required, it has nothing to do with .Net. `VBA/VB != C#` (or whatever the not-equals operator is in that language).

Comment: >> VBA/VB != C#   No question there.  Pity about all that typing. ;-)

Comment: Nice it solve the problem, Thanks! and of course you can use "With" in c# I just not like it hehe